# WebClient - DownloadFileAsync not working when called second time

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient, .net-4.6

I've build simple method that downloads single file. When I call that method first time everything works fine, but when called second time file isn't downloaded.
Below is my code:

```
public void DownloadFile(string fileUrl, string path)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null & !e.Cancelled)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"Download completed!");
            }
        };

        var url = new Uri(fileUrl);

        try
        {
            webClient.OpenRead(url);
            string headerContentDisposition = webClient.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
            string filename = new ContentDisposition(headerContentDisposition).FileName;

            Debug.WriteLine(filename);

            path = Path.Combine(path, filename);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(url, path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I've identified part that is breaking my download, it is part that is responsible for getting file name:

```
webClient.OpenRead(url);
string headerContentDisposition = webClient.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
string filename = new ContentDisposition(headerContentDisposition).FileName;
```

If I replace that part with `string filename = "1.tmp";` I'm able to call my method multiple times without errors.

I'm calling that method by clicking button with this click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string url = @"http://www.jtricks.com/download-text";
    const string target = @"D:\TEMP\";
    DownloadFile(url, target);
}
```

After two click on button without code that is getting file name I get this output in console:

```
1.tmp
Download completed!
1.tmp
Download completed!
```

Below is gif showing this working fine:
[image]

When I add back part that is getting file name this is my output:

```
content.txt
Download completed!
content.txt
```

Below gif showing that behavior:
[image]

Second time I click Start I'm getting file name, but download don't start, next click blocks start button.

How can I fix this? Ideally I'd like to call `DownloadFile` as many time I need.

Comment: I am very shocked your code works at all considering you don't block after calling `DownloadFileAsync` and your WebClient should be getting disposed of before the download even finishes. Also, you call `webClient.OpenRead(url);` but you don't do anything [with the stream it is returning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/781fwaz8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've build my code based on blog entry I found - http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/227/how-to-download-a-webfile-with-csharp-and-show-download-progress-synchronously-and-asynchronously. I was sure that async inside using will fail, but it works.

Comment: That blog is a very very bad example of what to do, it is making mistakes all over the place, I would not trust any posts from that author, they do not appear to know what they are doing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've found second example using lock and Monitor - https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/09/14/how-to-use-net-webclient-synchronously-and-still-receive-progress-updates/ is this better?

Comment: @Misiu were you ever able to figure this out? We are having exactly the same issue!

Comment: @nicV it was some time ago, but Yes, I think that the key was to specify `KeepAlive = false`. You can use this version of WebClient class: https://github.com/stenlytw/UVa-ASP.NET/blob/master/UVA/NoKeepAlivesWebClient.cs. Let me know if that helped

Comment: @Misiu Thanks for answering! It was a long shot! I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work. I think we will need to rework it to use HttpClient instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `WebClient`is using a Cache. I suggest that you have to tell `WebClient` not to use caching:

```
webClient.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
```

Comment: I'll try that right away. I've started rewriting my code to use `HttpClient`, but  it is hard to get progress of download file there, so if Your suggestion will help then I'll leave this code

Comment: I've tried Your code, but unfortunately it didn't helped. My application still behave as shown on second gif in my question.