# Stream.CopyToAsync with progress reporting - progress is reported even after copying finish

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.6

I've build a simple console applications that download files from the internet.
Because [I had problems with WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640955/webclient-downloadfileasync-not-working-when-called-second-time) I decided to write my app using HttpClient.

Basically I'm doing request to read headers, then using `ReadAsStreamAsync` I'm getting stream which I'm copying to local file using `CopyToAsync`.

I've found extension method for stream that supports IProgress:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, IProgress<long> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead;
        long totalRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
        {
            await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
            progress.Report(totalRead);
        }
    }
}
```

My application works, but I get incorrect progress information.
For example when downloading 2 files I see this in output window:

```
file1.tmp 60.95%
file2.tmp 98.09%
file1.tmp 60.98%
file2.tmp 98.21%
file2.tmp 98.17%
file2.tmp 98.25%
file1.tmp 61.02%
file2.tmp 98.41%
file2.tmp downloaded
file2.tmp 98.29%
file2.tmp 98.37%
file1.tmp 61.06%
file2.tmp 89.27%
file2.tmp 89.31%
file2.tmp 98.33%
file2.tmp 98.45%
file2.tmp 98.48%
file1.tmp 61.10%
file1.tmp 61.14%
file2.tmp 98.52%
file1.tmp 61.22%
file2.tmp 98.60%
file2.tmp 98.56%
file1.tmp 61.30%
file2.tmp 98.88%
file2.tmp 90.44%
file1.tmp 61.53%
file2.tmp 98.72%
file1.tmp 61.41%
file1.tmp 61.73%
file2.tmp 98.80%
file1.tmp 61.26%
file1.tmp 61.49%
file1.tmp 61.57%
file1.tmp 61.69%
...
file1.tmp 99.31%
file1.tmp 98.84%
file1.tmp 98.80%
file1.tmp 99.04%
file1.tmp 99.43%
file1.tmp 99.12%
file1.tmp 99.00%
file1.tmp downloaded
file1.tmp 100.00%
file1.tmp 98.73%
file1.tmp 98.88%
file1.tmp 99.47%
file1.tmp 99.98%
file1.tmp 99.90%
file1.tmp 98.96%
file1.tmp 99.78%
file1.tmp 99.99%
file1.tmp 99.74%
file1.tmp 99.59%
file1.tmp 99.94%
file1.tmp 98.49%
file1.tmp 98.53%
ALL FILES DOWNLOADED
file1.tmp 99.55%
file1.tmp 98.41%
file1.tmp 99.62%
file1.tmp 98.34%
file1.tmp 99.66%
file1.tmp 98.69%
file1.tmp 98.37%
```

As You can see I got info that file2 is downloaded, but I'm still getting progress report from `CopyToAsync` , same with file1.

because of that I sometimes get this weird console output:

[image]

Ideally I'd like to be sure than when I call:

```
await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo, progress, source.Token,0x2000);
Debug.WriteLine(filename+" downloaded");
```

after I get that debug information no progress is reported (file is downloaded). I thought that `await` will solve my problem, but is doesn't.

How can I fix this? As a temporary solution I'm adding Thread.Sleep to `CopyToAsync` just before I report progress.

Below is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncDownloadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string LocalPath = @"D:\TEMP";

        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var filesToDownlad = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
                {
                    new Tuple<string, string>("file1.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"),
                    new Tuple<string, string>("file2.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip")
                };
                _consolePosition = -1;
                Console.CursorVisible = false;

                Parallel.ForEach(filesToDownlad, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, doc =>
                {
                    DownloadFile(doc.Item2,doc.Item1).Wait();
                });
                Debug.WriteLine("ALL FILES DOWNLOADED");
                Console.CursorVisible = true;    
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static readonly object ConsoleLock = new object();
        private static int _consolePosition;

        static readonly CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        private static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string filename)
        {
            int currenctLineNumber = 0;
            int currectProgress = 0;

            try
            {
                lock (ConsoleLock)
                {
                    _consolePosition++;
                    currenctLineNumber = _consolePosition;
                }

                long fileSize = -1;

                IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(value =>
                {
                    decimal tmp = (decimal)(value * 100) / fileSize;

                    if (tmp != currectProgress && tmp > currectProgress)
                    {
                        lock (ConsoleLock)
                        {
                            currectProgress = (int)tmp;
                            Console.CursorTop = currenctLineNumber;
                            Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                            Console.Write("{0,10} - {2,11} - {1,6:N2}%", filename, tmp, "DOWNLOADING");
                        }
                        Debug.WriteLine("{1} {0:N2}%", tmp, filename);
                    }
                });

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, source.Token))
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue) fileSize = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value;

                        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
                        {
                            var tmp = response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                            Debug.WriteLine("Real name: {0}",tmp);
                        }

                        using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                        {
                            using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(Path.Combine(LocalPath, filename), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo, progress, source.Token,0x2000);

                                Debug.WriteLine(filename+" downloaded");

                                lock (ConsoleLock)
                                {
                                    Console.CursorTop = currenctLineNumber;
                                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                                    var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                                    Console.Write("{0,10} - {2,11} - {1,6:N2}%", filename, 100, "SUCCESS");
                                    Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                lock (ConsoleLock)
                {
                    Console.CursorTop = currenctLineNumber;
                    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                    var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.Write("{0,10} - {2,11} - {1,6:N2}%", filename, currectProgress, "ERROR");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class StreamExtensions
    {
        public static async Task CopyToAsync(this Stream source, Stream destination, IProgress<long> progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken), int bufferSize = 0x1000)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            long totalRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
            {
                await destination.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                totalRead += bytesRead;
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                progress.Report(totalRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with using `async`, but rather with your code setting the wrong row/column when outputting to the console. Something with your `lock` is wrong, but I did not investigate any further.

Comment: @Krumelur thanks for comment, even when I remove Console related code I can still see in VS Output window that I get `file2.tmp downloaded` but after that I still get progress reports, just as show in my question (second code section that stars with `file1.tmp 60.95%` )

Comment: Be careful doing `DownloadFile(doc.Item2,doc.Item1).Wait();` in a `Parallel.ForEach`, the `Parallel` class will use the calling thread as one of the worker threads, if that calling thread has a `SynchronizationContext` you will deadlock the program. You may want to look in to [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of using `Parallel`, it has methods that support async functions being passed in so you can just pass `DownloadFile` directly instead of having to call `.Wait()` on it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thans for comment, I've tried looking at TPL Dataflow, however I don't have idea how to convert my code in a way to use it. Could You try to convert it and post it as an answer? This would help me a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is actually here:

```
new Progress<long>
```

The `Progress<T>` class [*always* invokes its callbacks in a `SynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d0dc5fc099946adc1035b34a8b1f6042eddb0c75/src/System.Threading/src/System/Progress.cs#L76) - which in this case is the thread pool `SynchronizationContext`. This means that when the progress reporting code calls `Report`, it's just queueing the callback to the thread pool. So, it's possible to see them out of order (or still coming in a bit after the download has actually finished).

To fix this, you can create your own custom implementation of `IProgress<T>`:

```
//C#6.0
public sealed class SynchronousProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
  private readonly Action<T> _callback;
  public SynchronousProgress(Action<T> callback) { _callback = callback; }
  void IProgress<T>.Report(T data) => _callback(data);
}
//older version
public sealed class SynchronousProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _callback;

    public SynchronousProgress(Action<T> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    void IProgress<T>.Report(T data)
    {
        _callback(data);
    }
}
```

Then replace the line

```
IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(value =>
```

with

```
IProgress<long> progress = new SynchronousProgress<long>(value =>
```

Comment: Thank You for Your reply. I've used Progres because I thought it will do it's job. Maybe Action or simple Delegate would be better? I'll try Your solution in a moment, but maybe there is a better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The OP requested I show how to do his program with TPL Dataflow in the comments. It is actually a rather simple conversion. First add a reference to the NuGet package [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow). Then just change your main function to

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        var filesToDownlad = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("file1.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("file2.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip")
        };
        _consolePosition = -1;
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        var downloadBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, string>>(doc => DownloadFile(doc.Item2, doc.Item1),
                                                                   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4});

        foreach (var file in filesToDownlad)
        {
            downloadBlock.Post(file);
        }
        downloadBlock.Complete();
        downloadBlock.Completion.Wait();


        Debug.WriteLine("ALL FILES DOWNLOADED");
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If you where doing this with a program with a synchronization context and you wanted to await the completion and posting instead of doing synchronous operations you could do

```
static async Task Example()
{
    try
    {
        var filesToDownlad = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("file1.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("file2.tmp", "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip")
        };
        _consolePosition = -1;
        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        var downloadBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<string, string>>(doc => DownloadFile(doc.Item2, doc.Item1),
                                                                   new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4});

        foreach (var file in filesToDownlad)
        {
            await downloadBlock.SendAsync(file);
        }
        downloadBlock.Complete();
        await downloadBlock.Completion;


        Debug.WriteLine("ALL FILES DOWNLOADED");
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Note, this does not fix your problem of "ALL FILES DOWNLOADED" running early. You need to use [Stephen's solution to fix that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39744807/80274). All this does is fix a potential deadlock if this code was running in a situation where there could be a `SynchronizationContext` on the calling thread.

Comment: Thank You for posting this code. I thought it will be hard to Dataflow, but code looks clear. DataFlow is something I must definitively look at!